# iOS TestFlight build update to AppStore build

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have some scenarios that am not really sure about regarding TestFlight and AppStore:

1. The user has **version 1.0** installed on device from **TestFlight** and then he updates to the same **version 1.0** from **AppStore**. What happens, the build is just **overwritten**?
2. The user has **version 1.0** installed on device from **TestFlight** and then he updates to a newer **version 1.1** from **AppStore**. What happens, the build is just **overwritten**? What is the **difference** between this case and the previous one?
3. The same as case 1. does the user receive any **notification** that the application is available on AppStore?

Any other observations are appreciated.
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer 1 & 2** :-

Yeah the app will be overwritten. It will be like a regular app update from the app store. All the data that is saved in the test flight app also will be preserved when you install the app from app store.

**Question 3** - No there will not be any notification in the testflight app if the application is available in the app store.